# How to work with encrypted data that's in the KeyStore

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, encryption

I am trying to make an Android application, in Kotlin, to save my passwords. For that reason I would like them to be encrypted. I have been following a tutorial that has helped me to create the encryption system, but I don't really know how to use it to save various values.

As I said, my program is based on saving my passwords. My idea is to make an Activity to enter the passwords, and another to decrypt them. For example, you would put in an entry "Amazon", and the previously entered password of Amazon would come out.

Let me explain: the system I have now is capable of encrypting a text, giving me the encrypted data together with an IV. Obviously these two values ​​change every time, but how can I use them later to decrypt a specific password? In other non-password related projects I have used getPreferences (Context.MODE_PRIVATE) .edit (). PutString to save data, but from what I understood the KeyStore is used for encrypted data.

I would be very grateful if you could help me solve my doubts and solve these problems: understand how to save the IV and the encrypted data in the KeyStore, how I can later decrypt them and know that I am removing those and not those of another password.

I've been looking for a long time, both in forums and in the Android documentation, but I have not been able to get anything clear.

The code I have so far is [here](https://github.com/Tupiet/PassOwl-Kotlin), and the tutorial I followed is [this](https://youtu.be/Adqcm-BFioo).

In this code (MainActivity.tk), there is the buttonEncrypt function. This function is called by a button, which in turn displays the IV and the encrypted password in the UI, as well as the decryption. I'm stuck at this point, in how to get that result.first and result.second from outside that function, as there will be a dedicated button to decrypt. Now, a single function (the last) is outputing the encrypted data and the decrypted.

Thank you very much, and I hope you can help me, it would be a great help. All the best.

Comment: Why do you want to store your encrypted data/iv in the keystore ? IV don't need to to be kept secret, and the encrypted data is ...  well, encrypted

Comment: So, I could easily store the IV and the encrypted data like I've already done, using getPreferences().edit().putString?